# can i ask in trigger flow if rich text fields in changed

Tags: trigger

I was required to build an automatic process that is activated when a change is made to a record in a rich text field, is it possible to do this?

Comment: Hi @Rachel - do you mean "Record-triggered" flow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Apex` is capable of reading the value of these fields and comparing them, so as long as you use an `Apex Trigger`, you will be able to check for changes in fields of this type.